# JavaScript DOM audio not playing

Tags: javascript, dom, audio, html5-audio

Okay, I'm losing my mind here.

I'm trying to code a very simple player just for myself -- something crude but functional.

```
<button onclick="javascript:PlayAudio();">Play</button>
<script>
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "file.mp3"; // this file is in the same directory as the html page
var PlayAudio = function()
{
    audio.play();
};
</script>
```

Should work, right? I know it's not the BEST way to do it, but here's the thing: I've rewritten this code a couple hundred times and nothing seems to be working. There aren't even any error codes/exceptions/whatever that I can find. The browser says it's loaded the file just fine. What's even weirder is when I check the `paused` member in the `audio` object, no matter how many times I call the `play()` method, it still returns `true`.

When I load the page just as a file in my browser, lo and behold, it plays! Just fine! But if I were to change the `onclick` event to `audio.play();`, it doesn't work anymore. I want to run this on a server though.

I promise you there is no additional code. No JQuery, no weird server plugins (not even PHP!). Just Apache, Windows, nothing else.

And I know the browser can play the audio because when I copy `audio.src` and go to the address, it'll play just fine. Even the protocol is fine; the HTTP:/// address is not trying to load the File:/// address and vice versa. (I need the audio to play as a DOM so I can randomize the audio file later on; I'm just trying to get my browser to play one stinkin' file in the first place.)

I know I can do this in HTML with some JavaScript, but I know this can work in pure javascript too (ignoring the `<button>`) because I've done this before a LONG time ago. So what changed?

I've also tried to load the definitions using `window.onload`, but that doesn't work neither.

So... what the heck? I'm am stupid or something? I can accept that; I just need to know.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `javascript:` in the `onclick` attribute – that might be the cause? Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I do that because I'm a bit old-school. It shouldn't be the problem. Plus, I did lie a little bit; there is a ```console.log("???")``` call in ```PlayAudio()```, and it prints out those question marks, so it IS being called.

Comment: And there are no other messages shown in the console? (And perhaps these are obvious problems, but to check: your sound is on? The right output device is selected?)

Comment: There are no other messages in the console. I can play the audio file directly in the browser by going to its address; I can even play it as an audio element in HTML. But it fails in JavaScript with no error nor warnings of any kind.

Comment: Turns out, the code works fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome. Thank you, everyone, for helping out.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of the `path` to the `mp3` file. Also, separate your `HTML` from `JavaScript` code like so:

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn">Play</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const btnSound = document.querySelector('#btn');

btnSound.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const sound = new Audio('./file.mp3') // assuming it's in the directory
    sound.play();
});
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, if that narrows it down. Anyway, the path is valid because when I write it in HTML, it works. But I need this to work in JavaScript so my code can be easier to maintain down the road.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but I don't think this is a good answer, because both things it suggests are addressed by the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to create a dynamic audio element in pure Javascript...

- Create a div on your document to act as container for the dynamic tag
- in JS, create the audio element then add to page (via adding it to Div container)

Then you can try a code setup like this...

```
<div id="container">
<button onclick="PlayAudio('file.mp3')">Play</button>
<div>

<script>

//#create new audio tag
var myAudioElement = document.createElement( "audio");
myAudioElement.setAttribute("controls", "true" );
//myAudioElement.setAttribute("id", "myAudioTag"); //# if you'll need access "by ID"

//# add element to page DOM
document.getElementById('container').appendChild( myAudioElement );

function PlayAudio ( inputURL) //# input is a String like "file.mp3"
{
    myAudioElement.setAttribute("src", inputURL);
    myAudioElement.play();
}

</script>
```

Note: To run the `playAudio()` function without clicking a button just call:

```
PlayAudio ( "someOtherFile.mp3" );
```

**PS:** Below is an example of a *"better"* approach. Better here means less headaches (more intuitive) but it uses the HTML that you want to avoid. Notice no `.src` is specified because you can still use JS to update such property by code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Test Audio Playback </h1>

<audio id="myAudioTag" controls> <source src=" " type="audio/mpeg"> </audio>

<br>
<button onclick="PlayAudio();"> Play </button>

</body>

<script>
var audio = document.getElementById("myAudioTag");
audio.src = "file.mp3"; // this file is in the same directory as the html page

function PlayAudio() { audio.play(); }

//# call this function whenever track must be changed
//# example use:  changeAudio( "https://example.com/files/song2.mp3" );
function changeAudio( inputURL) //is a String of some other mp3 file
{
    audio.src = inputURL;
    audio.play();
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: PS: Code is tested in Chrome and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Write your code like this

```
<button onclick="PlayAudio();">Play</button>
<script>

var PlayAudio = function()
{
    var audio = new Audio("file.mp3")
    audio.play();
};
</script>
```

If it still does not work then also try to write onClick

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it didn't work. The ```audio``` object is being defined in the global scope, so it should still be accessible in the PlayAudio scope.

Comment: seems to be copied from the answer already submitted

Comment: @AnthumChris no i wrote it by my self

Comment: @zeroslash do you get any error in console ?

Comment: Nope, not even a cough from my browser. I'm downloading Firefox now to see if that'll behave differently.

Comment: Firefox works. Chrome is a pile of poop. I'm going back to C++ where things make more sense lol

Comment: Have fun with c++